How to change the data type of multiple variables in a data set in R
I want to change the datatype of multiple variables at once. Specifically I want to change multiple variables' datatype in an mpg dataset.
I tried with one variable, cyl:
mpg$cyl
as.factor(mpg$cyl)
mpg$cyl <- as.factor(mpg$cyl)

How can I change the displ and year datatype from numeric and integer to factor in a single command?

Welcome to SO, Srija Dutta! Please revisit the advice of how to enable others to help you and how to increase your chance of helpful feedback. That said, it looks like you're busy with the mtcars dataset. Do you perhaps mean mtcars$mpg and mtcars$cyl instead of mpg$cyl?

@I_O The OP is probably referring to ggplot2::mpg (which in contrast to mtcars has a year column).

df <- mpg; df[,c("displ", "year")] <- lapply(df[,c("displ", "year")], as.factor)

You can use the across() from dplyr to apply the same function to many columns.  For example
library(tidyverse)
mpg |> 
    mutate(across(c(displ, year), as.factor))

